# New directory: Knowledgebase

Tags: paclets

With the installation of Version 10.4, I've noticed a new directory at $UserBaseDirectory: Knowledgebase.

Contents appear to be (generally) binary -- either Dump[] files or Encrypt[], and their size ranges from Kb to Mb.

Could anyone comment on relationships between these and Paclets?